# How To Restart My Server In Java

Tags: java, restart

Well here is the shutdown method

```
public static void restart() {
    closeServices();
    System.gc();
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("run.cmd");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Logger.handle(e);
    }

}
```

And here is the run.cmd

```
java -javaagent:"C:\Program Files (x86)\ZeroTurnAround\JRebel\jrebel.jar" -cp bin;data/FileStore.jar;data/netty-3.5.2.Final.jar;xstream-1.4.3.jar;data/mysql.jar com.rs.Launcher
```

How do I make it show that it runs run.cmd and closes the last one? Right now all it does is just exit the current server and doesn't startup a new one.

Comment: I'm not certain, but most likely, killing the VM will also kill all child processes.

Comment: Does your `closeServices();` ensure that the previous instance has shutdown before you start creating a new one? and +1 with @Jochen

Comment: Your native exec handling might not know to execute .cmd files with CMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another batch script with

```
taskkill /F /IM java.exe
```

And this will surely do.

Programmatically:-

```
public static void restart() {
    closeServices();
    System.gc();
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM java.exe");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Logger.handle(e);
    }    
}
```